# Can I generate in-routine documentation that will appear in doxygen report?

Tags: doxygen

I've just started using doxygen to document some legacy C code and I'm very impressed about what in can do even with un-marked up code.   I've gotten the basics, annotating routines:  brief, description, param, return, see, etc.   That all appears (beautifully) in the generated documentation for the function.  My question is: Can I put doxygen markup inside the routine, interspersed in the actual code, so comments that explain the "upcoming" section of code, can also be included in the documentation.  Providing a stepwise overview of what the function does without having to copy those comments to the top of the routine?

Comment: Maybe you should give it a try and also look at `\internal` and `INTERNAL_DOCS`

Comment: It appears the internal flags are only used to expand the regular documentation output with additional commentary for internal use only, not for comments internal to a code block.